# How to copy an entire folder from s3 bucket to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can't seem to find a command to copy an entire folder and its contents from an s3 bucket to my ec2 instance.

I tried the following command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://${AuthorizedKeyBucketName}/datasets/ .
```

Here, datasets is a folder that exists in the root of my s3 bucket, and it has nested folders within itself as well. When I try to run the command, I get HeadObject error, no such object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [synchronize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command:

```
aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/datasets/ .
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I run this command, not even an error. Your thoughts?

Comment: The command copied from S3 to the local directory. Perhaps there is nothing in that S3 location? Use `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/datasets/` to view the content. (And, of course, replace `my-bucket` with your bucket name.)